# How to pass methods to the services from module where they are used ?(ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example, I have 
main_file.rb

```
 module Exporter
   extend self

   def transfer(params1, params2)
     Services::Transfer.call(params1, params2)
   end

   def get_sender(params1)
     #some_code
   end
 end
```

and services/transfer.rb

```
module Services
  module Transfer
    def self.call(params1, params2)
      sender = get_sender(params1)
      #some_code
    end
  end
end
```

And i can't define `get_sender` method exactly in services/transfer.rb as it is used in other services like services/transfer.rb.

Comment: You mean `include Exporter` inside either `module Services` or `module Transfer`?

Comment: @MicaelNussbaumer can i pass these method as a parameter in `transfer()` method and it can be available in `Servises::Transfer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you do not need to `extend self`. Either use `module_method` to declare methods as both module and instance, or, which is in your case more appropriate, use an explicit module function declaration.

```
module Exporter
 def self.transfer(*params)
   Services::Transfer.call(self, :get_sender, *params)
 end

 def self.get_sender(params1)
   #some_code
 end
end

module Services
  module Transfer
    def self.call(receiver, method, *params)
      sender_param, *other_params = params
      sender = receiver.public_send(method, sender_param)
      #some_code
    end
  end
end
```

This approach is more generic and probably should suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to use `Exporter`'s method `get_sender()` on other modules you can:

```
module Services
  module Transfer
    include Exporter
    def self.call(params1, params2)
      sender = get_sender(params1)
      #some_code
    end
  end
end
```

This allows you to use directly `get_sender()` inside the module, or `Services::Transfer.get_sender()`, actually any method in Exporter (which is being 'include'd) will be available to the module/class including it.